# Method write data of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie with the database MongoDB

I have read a little about the method of writing data for MongoDB. When I insert one document into the collection, this data will not be ready to store physically and will save to RAM, **about 60 seconds** after then it will write from RAM to the store physically.

**My question:** Is this precisely the method MongoDB is using? If not then someone can help explain the technique save data from MongoDB.

I thank you and waiting for your information.

Comment: This applies to most database technology out there. Databases can't be writing to disk on every write request. Mongodb writes journal at about 100ms (default)

Comment: Yeah 100ms is one triggering condition for MongoDB. More are described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/storage/#how-frequently-does-wiredtiger-write-to-disk-) (journal section)